# Bash script catch exit code of another bash script over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, exit-code

I'm writing a script *execute.sh* that ssh to other host and execute bash script from another file. The problem is I don't know how to catch exit code of the file I executed.
My execute.sh is like this:

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST 'bash -s' < ./onvps.sh
```

and I want *execute.sh* catch exit code of *onvps.sh*.

Thank you all.

Comment: `&&` will work on exit codes

Comment: You can use the `$?` following the `ssh` command (with no intervening commands)

Answer (score 0):

As the ssh client will exit with the exit code of the remote command, you can check the value of **$?**. if it return 0, it indicates that command is executed successfully.

in your case

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST 'bash -s' < ./onvps.sh
return_code=$?
# then evaluate 
if [ $return_code -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "ERROR"
fi
```

One example

```
$ more mytest.sh
exit 22
$ ssh myuser@myhost 'bash -s' < ./mytest.sh
$ echo $?
22
```

whatever you are including in the script will be executed in the remote, so `$?` will give you the exit code of it.

Comment: I try your solution but it's not work. The `echo $?` just return 0 because ssh to the remote host successfully. But what I want is the exit code that come from result of _onvps.sh_

Comment: the echo $? will give you the exit code of the remote shell execution. If you want the output of the other script, not the return code, then it is something else